# Can you use civicrm for inbound marketing instead of HubSpot?

Tags: drupal, email, evaluating-civicrm

We are considering using HubSpot with our Drupal 6 website to help with lead generation. Is anyone using civicrm for his purpose? Can civicrm create workflows once someone opts in via a form?

Specifically, we want to create landing pages with opt-in forms to capture web visitors' first name, last name and emails. Once we have that lead information, we want to be able to send them auto responder emails with messages that link to or contain content like white papers, video, text attachments etc. on a specific schedule. For example, we want an automated workflow that would send a lead something right after they submit info, then send another piece of content 2 days later, then a week later, and 2 weeks later. This automated workflow, landing page, and all the data about visitor behavior with this content is what HubSpot provides.

Comment: Thanks for your post.  You are more likely to get useful answers to this question if you could edit your question to provide more detail and outline the functionality you are looking for.  I'm not familiar with HubSpot and I'm guessing that others may not be also.

Answer (score 5):

You can create webforms with CiviCRM to capture the data you're requesting.  With the [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) extension, you can easily send automated email on a schedule like you describe.  In fact, CiviRules was originally created to do almost exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use webforms and scheduled reminders if you get the webform to create an activity when it is submitted. The activity created date will be the trigger for the scheduled reminders. However, you can only include links to content not attachments in scheduled reminders.

Comment: Would this work to add attachments to reminders? I haven't tried it though. https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-template-attachments